# CSS transform rotate on Y axis always showing the same face

Tags: css, animation, rotation, slider

I would like to make a slider a bit like this example:
https://codepen.io/zhangzor/pen/XWKxNJN?editors=1100

The squares should always show the same face and not move like a turnstile, but I can't seem to do that? When I update the rotate boxes individually, their position is reset.

Do you know how to do this with pure CSS (no Three.js or other libraries)?

Thank you and have a good day

```css
body {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
}

.box:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.box div:first-child {
  transform: rotateY(0) translateZ(300px);
}

.box div:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.box div:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.box div:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.box div:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(300px);
}

.box div:last-child {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rotation of inner `div`s depends on `.box` rotation so controlling them directly becomes a mess since their X an Y axis rotates with a `.box`.
But You can apply alternate rotation to their inner elements, using `div`s as moving containers.

https://codepen.io/accwatcp-the-vuer/pen/eYRdWZz

To transfer parent pre-rotation parameter to children just put it in css-variable - then it can be used for all its children elements. That will be used in counter rotation animation styling.
Now every child have its `--shift` parameter and can evaluate `--shift2` (shift to) final counter-rotation parameter.
Also put repeated Z coordinate for translation to variable, just for ease of use.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

body {
    perspective: 1000px;
 }

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 150px auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  animation: move 10s linear infinite;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}

.box:hover, .box:hover span {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes backmove {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(var(--shift));
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(var(--shift2));
  }
}

div {
  --shiftZ:350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
}
.box div:first-child {
  --shift:0deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}

.box div:nth-child(2) {
  --shift:60deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}

.box div:nth-child(3) {
  --shift:120deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}

.box div:nth-child(4) {
  --shift:180deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}

.box div:nth-child(5) {
  --shift:240deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}

.box div:last-child {
  --shift:300deg;
  transform: rotateY(calc(var(--shift)*(-1))) translateZ(var(--shiftZ));
}
span{
  --shift2:calc(var(--shift) - 360deg);
  display:flex;
  background-color: #f003;
  border:1px dashed black;
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  animation: backmove 10s linear infinite;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  font-size:5rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="box">
  <div><span>1</span></div>
  <div><span>2</span></div>
  <div><span>3</span></div>
  <div><span>4</span></div>
  <div><span>5</span></div>
  <div><span>6</span></div>
</section>
```